# Giving schedule time less time 1 minutes in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am doing cron job in my application and I would like to run those cron jobs in every 5 seconds. So I make it schedule time in cron.xml to 5 seconds and 0.1 minutes but those can't make in cron job and I got fail to parse error.
below is How I configure in cron.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/cron/threadchacker</url>
        <target>beta</target>
        <description>daily summary job</description>
        <schedule>every 5 seconds</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

Answer (score 1):

Format for [cron regular schedule](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cronref#schedule_format) is:

```
every N (hours|mins|minutes) ["from" (time) "to" (time)]
```

Where N is integer number. So 1 minute is minimum period.

What you can do is to have a cron job that every minute queue few delayed tasks (*see `countdownMillis` in [TaskOptions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions#method-detail)*)

- 1 with 5 seconds delay
- 1 with 10 seconds delay
- 1 with 15 seconds delay
- etc.